# Android MediaRecorder low audio volume on some devices (HTC ONE S)

Tags: android, media-player, volume, mediarecorder

I created android app recording a bit of audio with the following code (taken from official android developer guide)

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();       
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
final String fileName = getFileName();
recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to prepare recorder", e);
}
recorder.start();
```

After recording I playback recorded audio with

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(new FileInputStream(getFileName()).getFD());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

I also analyze audio while recording calling 
    recorder.getMaxAmplitude();

I ran this on two devices: HTC ONE S (with Android 4) and quite low end Samsung Galaxy Young (GT-S5360, with Android 2.3.6).
I try to record some background noises (radio on in the same room).
What is very disappointing is that the samsung device reports amplitudes on level of above 1000, and sometimes above 10 000, while HTC top end device reports amplitudes on level of below 1000 (200-400). In accordance with these amplitudes, audio playback gives very poor volume on the htc device, while samsung recorded audio has volume on accepted level. (Both devices have media volume set to high).

But when I use the factory provided video/audio recording application on the htc device, when I playback it, the audio seems on incredibly sensitive level.

I tried recording with all available MediaRecorder.AudioSource values and it's the same for most of them, while mysteriously not workingo for some (VOICE_CALL, VOICE_UPLINK)
Any idea what could be wrong here?

Best regards,
Mikolaj

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Have the same issue on htc one x with 4.1.1 using         setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);Did not find solution yet.